# how JVM does memory management(or efficiently use memory) for the interface references?

Tags: java

we always use this code

```
List mylist=new ArrayList();
```

I look this statement into deep and i found that mylist is an interface reference which is referring to the ArrayList which is a class.I found(on internet) that there is some benefits of it like Loose coupling ,memory management etc.But How ?what are the benefits of using interface refernce?

Comment: Several well documented reasons, but memory management most definitely is not one of them. You might be confusing interfaces with soft / weak references there.

Comment: You can later change it to a `LinkedList`, for example.

Comment: could you explain the benefits of interface type references for ArrayList object ? What are the benefits or it is just a convention?

Comment: That is explained in the linked Q&A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no memory management benefits.

However, using the interface Type allows you to make use of polymorphism.
Here, it means you can use any class inheriting List as a working implementation replacement.

This is allowing loose coupling because you are not tied with ONE and ONLY list implementation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: i had seen the link but it just only tell about the Interface .I have still some doubt why we are using the Interface reference?